# How do I find the numeric code for the combination lock in Planetfall?

Tags: planetfall

In the text adventure Planetfall, there's a door which you can't get past without entering the right numeric code.

- What is the code?
- Where do I find the code?
- Assuming the door isn't a red herring, what's behind it?

Comment: Assuming it is the same door, Googling easily finds the answer.

Comment: @Mark: The purpose of this site is to be the repository for all gaming questions, so when someone googles this question, *this* is the page they find.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: I only added a comment because, at the time, there was no answer and, although I'd never played the game, a simple Google search found a couple of sites seeming to explain a numeric code for a door in Planetfall.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, You don't need to solve the the combination lock in the Rec Corridor.

The clue on how to open this lock can be found on a paper in a lab uniform pocket that located South of the Main Lab.

Answer (score 1):

The door isn't really important, but once you move to the second complex in the facility, it's quite easy to find.

> The note containing the combination is in the pocket of a lab uniform

To get to the second complex you need to ...

> Find the shuttle and learn how to operate it.

As far as I remember, the only relevant thing behind the door is ...

> teleporter room #1, allowing you a quicker route to the dorms when you need to sleep

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [manual](http://infodoc.plover.net/manuals/planetfa.pdf)? These games are meant to be played with manual, perhaps you'll find the answer there.

From scanning the manual, there might be alternative way how to get past the door - shooting the lock with a blaster, maybe.

Comment: Thank you for the handy manual PDF. Unfortunately, the manual does not contain a clue or answer to this puzzle. I used up all my blaster rounds shooting Floyd.